# how can a programmer work with a web designer with silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, expression-blend

we want to develop a silver light application. I am the programmer. management want to improve the Userinterface, so they want a web designer join the development. I am using VS2010 to develop the application. I know there is a tool callled expression blend, which is for designer. how can we work together. What is the best practice with this team of two of us.

Thanks.

David

Answer (score 2):

We have hired an outside design agency to help with the design for a large Silverlight LOB application. I would suggest that you start the process with paper and pencil, gather ideas, look & feel, etc. Also consider who your target audience is, we created Personas that represent specific types of user, if your users have an issue with the final UI/UX thats bad.

We then let the designer create parts of the UI in blend with nothing behind (or maybe a little just to test an idea or prove a point).

At the same time you can consider/design the overall flow of the application (screens/views/sub-views) and get your infrastructure running (ie. which MVVM approach you like, how to chop up the views with controls or usercontrols etc).

Bringing the visuals together with the code we then did at intervals. It proved to be an iterative process but having different perspectives as the project progressed helped smooth out issues as they presented.

Definitely talk through the process before starting.

Bit of a ramble but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about best practices for your situation, but Expression Blend can open the same project and solution files as Visual Studio, so you can both work from the same codebase.  Whether you'll be stepping on each others' toes or not is another story.  Perhaps somebody else will have more of an idea as to how the developer/designer dynamic works when working with Silverlight apps.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with understanding of MVVM pattern.

With MVVM pattern you can create two separate `ViewModels` for every View. One can be a real one with good functionality and the second one will be for the designer - to work with fake data in Blend. Then you can easily work on the functionality side of the application (`ViewMode` and `Model`) and the designer will tweak the GUI (`View`).

You can test in ServiceLocator if you're in Blend or in runtime and provide appropriate ViewModel.

One of the easiest (and good for working in Bled) MVVM framework is: [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/)